# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 using Visual Basic, how to correctly write in code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Currently I'm new to this and I'm attempting to get this all to work, right now I've looked into and made a module which allows to me to change the user-agent of the internal web-browser so I can manipulate it easily however this is where the issue lies.

I'm assuming I must be editing the auto generated code because the file itself is called "Form1.Designer.vb" and I have no idea where to start putting in custom code to override the current code such as I wanting to do something like this;

```
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.MinimumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Name = "WebSiteBrowser1"
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(671, 413)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.TabIndex = 0
    ChangeUserAgent("This is after the url agent gets changed after the first url open")
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/", Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent: This is the first open url agent")
```

However whenever I change anything in the visual template it automatically resets back to

```
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.MinimumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Name = "WebSiteBrowser1"
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(671, 413)
    Me.WebSiteBrowser1.TabIndex = 0
```

So my question is where do I write the custom code that would allow me to keep that after the auto-generation from the visual creator?

Comment: Too much things to explain. Perhaps you could find useful to follow some basic tutorials. Like this one http://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-a-Program-in-Visual-Basic-Web-Browser/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Just run your code on Form Load event. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting your code in the `form1.vb` and leave the designer file alone. In the `form1.vb[Design]` you can change the properties in the properties window. If it is not currently docked to the right side of the VS designer you can show it by going to the Menu -> `View` -> `Properties Window` and select it.